# Recording a customer's shopping cart as an order

Tags: java, mysql, error-handling, jdbc, e-commerce

I have come up with the following method to post a transaction to a database, in the context of an e-commerce Java web application. The transaction consists in submitting a new order alongside its details:

```
public long insertOrder(Customer customer, Hashtable<String, CartItem> shoppingCart)
{
    long returnValue = 0L;
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    try {
        connection = MySqlConnection.getConnection();
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        long orderId = System.currentTimeMillis();
        OrderPeer.insertOrder(statement, orderId, customer);
        OrderDetailsPeer.insertOrderDetails(statement, orderId, shoppingCart);
        connection.commit();
        returnValue = orderId;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try { connection.rollback(); } catch (Exception ex) { }
        System.out.println("Could not insert order: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try { statement.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
        try { connection.close(); } catch (Exception e) { }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

I would like to know if I am handling the exception, rolling back, and closing the statement/connection in the best possible manner.

Comment: Hi, I have rolled back your update, please see [What you may and may not do once you've received answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

Comment: @Zak Thanks for your accurate correction. I have read the referred resource and added my own answer as a consequence. Please, let me know if there's anything that could use further improvement.

Comment: Follow-up question here:  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117176/67620

Comment: @Zak I have posted a follow-up question, as per your suggestion. Hopefully, I'm doing better now. :)

Comment: Just make sure to add a link here pointing to your follow-up, and a link in your follow-up pointing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the ["try-with-resources"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement should clean up your code significantly. There are two advantages:

1. It allows you to declare your resources (in this case `Connection` and `Statement` objects) in exactly the scope they're going to be used. This means you don't have to first initialize them to `null`, which is ugly.
2. It will ensure your resources get closed no matter what.

Also, you should probably print the stack trace (to aid you and others in debugging), and you should print your error messages to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

```
public long insertOrder(Customer customer, Hashtable<String, CartItem> shoppingCart)
{
    try (Connection connection = MySqlConnection.getConnection();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        long orderId = System.currentTimeMillis();
        OrderPeer.insertOrder(statement, orderId, customer);
        OrderDetailsPeer.insertOrderDetails(statement, orderId, shoppingCart);
        connection.commit();
        return orderId;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        try {
           connection.rollback();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Could not roll back connection: " + ex.getMessage())
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        System.err.println("Could not insert order: " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace()l
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Would you mind expanding a bit on your advice?

Comment: There are some flaws in your code. For instance, the `connection.rollback()` is outside the scope of the `connection` variable, which only exists inside the body of the `try` construct.

Comment: I have used your suggestion to create a better version of my code and have added it as an update to my original question. It'd be great if you could take a look at it.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I didn't realize that `connection.rollback()` had to be explicitly called before `connection.close()` when doing a transaction. My experience with JDBC is limited.

It looks like the changes you made above solve the problem with my code. It's unfortunate that two `try ... catch ... ` blocks have to be used, but I don't see a cleaner solution.

Comment: @gardenhead I have placed a follow-up question with my improved version of the code. I thought you might want to take a look at it. You'll find its link in the comments section of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning long, with zero representative of either a failure to insert or a failed rollback, suggest returning objects instead. Objects could be created for narrower range of order id's, objects which had instance variable area to store specific success or failure details or provide useful predicate methods: isInsertOK, isRollback, etc.

Would be safer not to use long without any range. Risk may be unlikely now as method is small but suppose some error or corruption occurrs resulting in an invalid order id but valid long. These objects would consolidate repeated procedural code handling return codes, order id's, failures.